# show sql results in php with tables

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

Hi all I have some code that displays a table and rows, but all the results are being displayed in the same column, the first one. I would like to display the results in different columns. Thanks a lot

```
    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id
    </th><th>OFFER NAME
    </th><th>OFFER ID
    </th><th>TRAFICO
    </th><th>FILTRADAS
    </th><th>% FILTRADAS
    </th><th>INICIADAS
    </th><th>FINALIZADAS
    </th><th>UNSUCCESSFUL INSTALLS
    </th><th>% UNSUCCESSFUL INSTALLS
    </th><th>SUCCESSFUL INSTALLS
    </th><th>REVENUE
    </th><th>BIDDING SCORE
    </th></tr>";

$sql = "SELECT installs.advertiser_id FROM installs WHERE YEAR(installs.time_of_install) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(installs.time_of_install) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY installs.advertiser_id LIMIT 10";
$sql = "SELECT softwares.software_name FROM softwares LIMIT 10";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbDB", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT installs.advertiser_id FROM installs WHERE YEAR(installs.time_of_install) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(installs.time_of_install) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY installs.advertiser_id LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT softwares.software_name FROM softwares LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";


die;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `__construct` seem you don't call the proper function sequence for format (htlm) the row.

I think you should change you __construct someway for call beginChildren, current, endChildern properly

```
 function __construct($it) {
    beginChildren();
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    current();
    endChildren();
}
```